# Laravel: scripts and image source in layout is not working in url with prefix

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

> Route

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function()
{
    // home
    Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home', 'as' => 'home'));
    Route::get('home', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home', 'as' => 'home'));
    Route::get('/user/create', array('uses' => 'UserController@getCreate', 'as' =>'getCreate'));
    Route::get('/user/login', array('uses' => 'UserController@getLogin', 'as' =>'getLogin'));
    Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function()
        {
            Route::post('/user/create', array('uses' => 'UserController@postCreate', 'as' => 'postCreate'));
            Route::post('/user/login', array('uses' => 'UserController@postLogin', 'as' => 'postLogin'));
        });

});
```

I tried to add link to script files in my master.blade.php file as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

this will work properly in url:

localhost/public

But If I tried to view my page /user/login then bootstrap script is not working...
But if I specify link as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

then bootstrap script will work properly in **/user/login**
but it will not work in link without prefix

Comment: post your view code where you load bootstrap css and js

Comment: rewrite your question.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a stylesheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The link to the stylesheet is appended to the browser's current url. So for http://somedomain.com/, that becomes http://somedomain.com/css/bootstrap.min.css - but for http://somedomain.com/somefolder/, that becomes http://somedomain.com/somefolder/css/bootstrap.min.css

When you do this, however:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

What you're saying is "go one directory up, then append the link".

What you want is probably this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The `/` in the beginning says "go to the root of your domain", and then it appends the stylesheet link.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you have to add the CSS and JS like below. You are using blade!

```
{{HTML::style('css/default.min.css')}} <!-- For CSS -->

{{HTML::script('js/scripts.min.js')}} <!-- For JS -->
```

as per my example, do make sure that css is present in the css folder and js is present in the js folder.

```
public/css/default.min.css

public/js/scripts.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's a proper way to load resources Laravel**

```
{{ asset('image.jpg') }}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('style.css') }}" />
```